# Unable to activate Feature in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, central-administration, feature-activation, custom-timer-job

I created a timer job which will send a mail to all the user.It was working fine in dev server.So ,I change the "**SITE URL**" in SOLUTION properties to **prod server url**(http://*****_prod)  and added solution by power shell and deployed it in prod using CA.It deployed with no issue but feature was not activated by default.

I tried to activate feature manually from "Site setting -- > site collection feature" but I received error saying **"Unexpected error occurred"**.

I have "full control" on web application and scope of timer job is "Site".

Please guide me to move forward.

Comment: can you check the ULS logs for more info about the error, their are many reasons for this.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE error :access denied

Answer (score 0):

Timer jobs are deployed at Webapplication level. Try changing the scope to "Web Applciation".

Comment: I will do and let you know.But my question is same configuration ran in dev server were I created the timer job.The only thing I changed is "Site URL" in solution properties.

Comment: Can you share your feature activation code?

Comment: public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
        { 
            SPSite site = properties.Feature.Parent as SPSite;


            CreateJob(site); // Create new Job
        }

        

        private static void CreateJob(SPSite site)
        {
            SPTimerJob job = new SPTimerJob(JobName, site.WebApplication);

            job.Update();
        }

Comment: public SPTimerJob(string jobName, SPWebApplication webapp)
            : base(jobName, webapp, null, SPJobLockType.Job)
        {
            this.Title = "SPTimer Job";
        }

Comment: I tried by changing the  scope to Web application but issue remains same and I looked into logs it says "access denied".Suggest me on this ....

Comment: try using  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
      in creating job. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49222/access-denied-while-activating-custom-timer-job

Comment: Also check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22757/configure-sharepoint-user-for-timer-job and http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2564009